# Прошу совета по разработке Cordova

Tags: php, ajax, mobile-development, cordova

Хочу сделать мобильное кросс-платформенное приложение как instagram.
Функционал: загрузка фото, профили, лента, лайки и подобное.
Мною был получен совет, что минимальный порог вхождения у Cordova.
Начал изучать html, css, js, php.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что ещё мне надо изучить?

Стоит ли использовать ionic framework или что-то подобное, или это усложнит разработку для новичка?

Стоит ли использовать AJAX для исполнения php внутри приложения или лучше использовать js?

Какие js фреймворки пригодятся?

Comment: Во первых выяснить что же такое ajax

Comment: Js фреймворк брать в зависимости от того что вам нужно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первую очередь вам нужно хорошо знать **JavaScript**, желательно ECMAScript 6, а потом уже изучать различные фреймворки на подобии [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/), [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) или [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/). Можете почитать в интернете различные статьи и сравнения этих фреймворков и выбрать, что вам больше подходит, но я бы посоветовал React Native, т.к. он более производительный и в нём реализована многопоточность. Также в React есть большая кроссплатформенная библиотека для UI-элементов — [React Native Elements](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/), которая упрощает разработку приложения.

Если вы планируете ещё разрабатывать backend-часть, то вам нужно дополнительно знать какой-либо серверный язык: PHP, Python, Java и др., на котором вы будете её делать.

Comment: Логично. Без понимания _что такое молоток_ сложно _забить_ гвоздь, а не _согнуть_ его и _побить себе пальцы_.